# qt creator кодировка многобайтовая

Tags: qt, кодировка, creator

Как включить многобайтовую кодировку в qt creator ? Всё перелазил нигде не нашел)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в файл проекта (.pro файл, если используете QMake ):

```
DEFINES -= UNICODE
DEFINES += _MBCS
```